# SWT TableViewer color alternation (in some OS)

Tags: java, swt, jface

In some OS (like my Ubuntu 11.10) have interesting table elements behaviour: background color alternate from white to gray (1st element is white, 2nd is gray, 3rd is white, etc.).

In my application, I want to write my own `CellLabelProvider` for `JFace TableViewer` (it's necessary), and I'm using extention of class `OwnerDrawLabelProvider` (and overwriting paint method).

I want to paint specified rows in my own color, and other in system color `(Display.getCurrent().getSystemColor(...))`, but the problem is, that if I paint it in `SWT.COLOR_LIST_BACKGROUND`, then all rows are painted white, whitout alternation. How can i set it?

I debuged application, and realized, that both type of raws (white and grayed) have the samge color - white (and that is correct).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way to explicitly "owner-draw" it like the OS would. If you want a row to have its native background color you simply mustn't paint the background yourself.

Comment: Thanx for answer, too bad =/ There is another problem: if I dont paint all colors by myself, cells, that have my own OwnerDrawLabelProvider, and other cells, that have simple ColumnLabelProvider (there are both in my table) have slightly different behaviour: when I select row and then deactive table/window (like focus window over my application), OwnerDrawLabelProvider-cells remains selected-colored, but ColumnLabelProvider-cells became selected-grayed-colored (other color). And looks like this behaviour i cant "owner-draw" too... or not? Can u tell me something about it? Thanx again!

Comment: That's because your `OwnerDrawLabelProvider` paints the background of the cell if the row is selected. This happens in the `erase(..)` method. Override it with an empty method to stop it from doing that. The cell should then have its native behaviour.